# The class is missing from the schema for this Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

## Project setting

- Android studio 2.3.3
- Realm 3.5.0

## Source

### RealmController.java

```
public RealmController(Context context) {
    try {
        this.context = context;
        Realm.init(context);
        PrintLog("RealmController", "RealmController", "Init realm", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
        realmInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        PrintLog("RealmController", "RealmController", "Getting realm instance", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
    }
    catch (Exception err) {
        PrintLog("RealmController", "RealmController", "Error: " + err.getMessage(), LOG_LEVEL_ERROR);
    }
}
```

### SellingData.java

```
public class SellingDataTable extends RealmObject {

    public Date todaysDate;
    public int sellingData;

    public Date getTodaysDate() {
        return todaysDate;
    }
    public void setTodaysDate(Date todaysDate) {
        this.todaysDate = todaysDate;
    }
    public int getSellingData() {
        return sellingData;
    }
    public void setSellingData(int sellingData) {
        this.sellingData = sellingData;
    }
}
```

## Expected behavior

- Get realm default instance.

## Actual behavior

Gonna crash.

```
08-09 15:24:16.044 [I2maxMain] {Init} (preparing ui)
08-09 15:24:16.120 [RealmController] {RealmController} (Init realm)
08-09 15:24:16.129 [RealmController] {RealmController} (Error: The 'SellingDataTable' class is missing from the schema for this Realm.)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a Realm with a given schema on the device, then if you start modifying the schema (by adding new classes, adding new fields, removing fields, adding/removing `@Index`, adding/removing `@Required`, changing a type, etc.) then you either need to provide a migration (example [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/19e45278726ecb90f1d37b39146753b46537c4bb/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java)), or you need to specify `deleteIfMigrationNeeded()` on your RealmConfiguration.

Comment: Ty bro your keyword which is `deleteIfMigrationNeeded` makes me help.
This is my [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961456/realm-not-auto-deleting-database-if-migration-needed).

Answer (score 2):

If you have added a new model class. You need to uninstall the app and run again. It will solve the problem.